# How to get the Key from data snapshot in Firebase unity c#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a game using Unity and Firebase SDK. I want to get the key of circles in the image.

[image]

```
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
      .GetReference("live_games")
      .OrderByChild("gameId").EqualTo(GAME_KEY)
      .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
          if (task.IsFaulted)
          {
              // Handle the error...
          }
          else if (task.IsCompleted)
          {
              DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
              Debug.Log("the json " + snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
              Debug.Log("the key is "+ snapshot.Key);
              // Do something with snapshot...
          }
      });
```

I get the key as "live_games" not "0"

Comment: You will have to iterate the children in the snapshot.  The SDK doesn't know that you only expect one child from the query.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson Is there a different way to get only a single value in firebase? like limit?

Comment: What you're doing is correct.  Just look at the children of the snapshot to see if you got what you were looking for.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Doug Stevenson it worked

```
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
      .GetReference("live_games")
      .OrderByChild("gameId").EqualTo(GAME_KEY)
      .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
          if (task.IsFaulted)
          {
              // Handle the error...
          }
          else if (task.IsCompleted)
          {
              DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
              foreach(var child in snapshot.Children)
              {
                  Debug.Log("The Key"+child.Key);
              }
              // Do something with snapshot...
          }
      });
```